# How to work with TResourceStream using "TCHAR maps to" set to "char"?

Tags: c++builder

The project I'm working on requires resource management with `TCHAR maps to` set to **char**, for this I use `TResourceStream`. Previously I had no problems with `TCHAR maps to` set to **wchar_t**. I don't get compiler errors, but with `char` mapping I always get an error when trying to extract the resource named `"r_1"` (resource identifier):

> Error: Resource r_1 not found

I have read the documentation:

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TResourceStream.Create

https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/TCHAR_Mapping

Am I making a mistake, or maybe it can't be used from this mapping?

```
try
{
    const System::UnicodeString r1 = L"r_1";
    //int n1 = 1;
    //System::NativeInt ni;
    System::UnicodeString type ( L"RT_RCDATA" );
    wchar_t *pType = type.c_str();

    TResourceStream *pRStream = new TResourceStream((unsigned int)HInstance, r1, pType);
    ...
    delete pRStream;
    delete pType;
}
catch (const Exception &e)
{
    ...
    ShowMessage(L"Error: " + e.Message);
    return;                   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, DO NOT use `delete pType;` since `pType` is not pointing at memory that is allocated with `new`.  Your `UnicodeString type` variable owns the memory, so it will free the memory for you when it goes out scope.

That being said, the `TCHAR maps to` setting has NO EFFECT whatsoever on the code you have shown, since the `TCHAR` type is not being used anywhere in that code.

However, you SHOULD NOT be using a string value of `L"RT_RCDATA"` for the last parameter of `TResourceString`'s constructor. That is not the correct resource type for an `RCDATA` resource.  The Win32 API defines an `RT_RCDATA` constant as `MAKEINTRESOURCE(10)` (which does use `TCHAR`, btw), meaning the resource type is a numeric 10, not a string `"RC_DATA"`.  So you need to pass in an integer `10` that is type-casted to `System::Char*`, eg:

```cpp
TResourceStream *pRStream = new TResourceStream((unsigned int)HInstance, r1, reinterpret_cast<System::Char*>(10));
```

Or, you can use the Win32 API's `MAKEINTRESOURCEW()` macro (the Unicode version of `MAKEINTRESOURCE()`), which will cast an integer to `wchar_t*` (which is what `System::Char*` maps to on Windows):

```cpp
TResourceStream *pRStream = new TResourceStream((unsigned int)HInstance, r1, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(10));
```

Or, you can use an `RT_RCDATA` constant for better readability.  To avoid the `TCHAR` issue, the RTL's `System.Types` unit (at least in modern C++Builder versions) defines its own `RT_RCDATA` constant using `System::Char`, eg:

```cpp
#include <System.Types.hpp>

TResourceStream *pRStream = new TResourceStream((unsigned int)HInstance, r1, System::Types::RT_RCDATA);
```